Why is SUM not ignoring NULLs in functional form?
I have the following bit of code inside a functional select argument:
a: (enlist col)!enlist(sum;(enlist,`dealsA`dealsB`dealsC));

However, if any value within the three columns I am attempting to sum is NULL, then the result itself is NULL too despite the documentation stating that they are to be treated as 0.
I also tried to use sum/ instead but that gives the same large value for each row which tells me it's likely summing everything up and not just each row by row.
What am I missing here?

Going forward it would be helpful if you could provide an input table for your question and what you would expect

Try {sum each flip x}
q)![t;();0b;(enlist`col)!enlist(sum;(enlist,`dealsA`dealsB`dealsC))]
dealsA dealsB dealsC col
------------------------
       200    300
100           600
200    400
q)![t;();0b;(enlist`col)!enlist({sum each flip x};(enlist,`dealsA`dealsB`dealsC))]
dealsA dealsB dealsC col
------------------------
       200    300    500
100           600    700
200    400           600

It seems using sum on a matrix which includes nulls can return nulls, although sum works as expected on lists.
q)sum(0n 100 200;200 0n 400;300 600 0n)
0n 0n 0n
q){sum each flip x}(0n 100 200;200 0n 400;300 600 0n)
500 700 600f


This is documented behaviour for aggregations of nested list which contain nulls: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sum/#aggregating-nulls
Aggregating across either dimension is fine when applied explicitly to each sublist:
q)t:([]dealsA:1 2 3 0N;dealsB:0N 4 5 6;dealsC:10 0N 3 4)
q)sum t
dealsA| 6
dealsB| 15
dealsC| 17
q)sum each t
11 6 11 10

But not when applied to the matrix as a whole:
q)sum value flip t
0N 0N 11 0N


I am not sure why NULLS are threated differently in tables, but you can just use fill to fill the NULLS with 0
q)t:([] dealsA:1 2 3 0N; dealsB:0N 4 5 6; dealsC:10 0N 3 4)
q)t
dealsA dealsB dealsC
--------------------
1             10
2      4
3      5      3
       6      4
q)0^t
dealsA dealsB dealsC
--------------------
1      0      10
2      4      0
3      5      3
0      6      4
q)select dealsA+dealsB+dealsC from 0^t
dealsA
------
11
6
11
10
q)select c:dealsA+dealsB+dealsC from 0^t
c
--
11
6
11
10

